# Remote powershell command fails on windows 10 target

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell

I would like to connect to a windows 10 machine and run a remote command with powershell script. The script which runs on a windows 10 machine looks like

```
$RemoteMachine = "10.1.1.50"
$vcenter_server ="10.1.1.2"

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $RemoteMachine -force

$Username = 'user'
$Password = ' '
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred `
               -ScriptBlock { diskpart /s c:\diskman.txt }
```

However, the output says the machine is not accessible while the ping command works fine.

```
[10.1.1.50] Connecting to remote server 10.1.1.50 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. 
Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception 
for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles 
limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help 
topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (10.1.1.50:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken



PS C:\Users\user> ping 10.1.1.50

Pinging 10.1.1.50 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.1.1.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Any idea to find the root of the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that WinRM is actually enabled on the remote computer? That is, after all, what the error message is suggesting is the problem...

Comment: OK I run `winrm quickconfig` and it turns out that the network type was set to "public". After I change that to "private", the winrm command worked and so does ``invoke-command.